# Do Inner Join and execute Sp on Sql query

Tags: sql-server, search, inner-join

i have query for search data like this :

```
select top 100 *  from Payment 
where PayId is not null   and
PayAccount like '%10158002%'and 
PayCustName like '%XXXX XXXXX%'and 
PayAmount like '%429000%'and 
PayAmountPaid like '%429000%'and 
PayResponse like '%00%'and
PayRefNo like '%101306000013%'and
cast(PayDatetime as date) = ( select convert(date , '03/06/2013', 103)) 
order by PayDatetime DESC
```

and give me the result like this :

```
PayId   PayAccount  PayCustName PayAmount   PayAmountPaid   PayResponse PayRefNo    PayScreenText   PayReceiptText  PayDatetime PayBankCode
49       10158002   XXXX XXXXX  429000        429000         00        101306000013             xxx              xxx   2013-06-03 11:43:18.210  112
```

and i have todo like this to generate the `PayResponse  00` text which is `success` by doing inner join with other table :

```
select para.Value2
from Payment pay 
inner join
Parameter para
on pay.PayResponse = para.Value1
```

and i should do check if the refno is used by another table or no by using another inner join but it used an stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rintis_StatusReversal]
@RefNoPay as varchar (20),
@Count as int output,
@Response as int output,
@Text as varchar(20) output


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


        Select  @Count = COUNT(*)
        from
            payment Pay
                inner join
            Reversal Rev
                on Pay.PayRefNo = Rev.PayRefNo        
        where Pay.PayRefNo = @RefNoPay

        if @Count > 0
        Begin
        SET @Response = 1
        SET @Text = 'Reversed'
        End
        Else
        Begin
        SET @Response = 0
        SET @Text = 'Paid'
        End

select @Response , @Text
END
```

by execute the procedure i want to get the @text value which is `success` or `reversed`.
 and i want input the value to first query result to.

so the query that i wanna get is like this :

```
  PayId PayAccount  PayCustName PayAmount   PayAmountPaid   PayResponse PayRefNo    PayScreenText   PayReceiptText  PayDatetime PayBankCode RefStatus
    49       10158002   XXXX XXXXX  429000        429000         00        101306000013             xxx              xxx   2013-06-03 11:43:18.210  112 Success
```

is it possible to do that? i still confused with complex sql query. thks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. However, I would not use a Stored Procedure. Try a function instead which can simply be attached as a column to your SELECT and it returns the string you want. However, be prepared to loose a lot of performance, as the function will be called every single time a record complex is generated.

So I suggest you convert the above SP into a function returning a CHAR(20) for example and it should work. No need to link it as a table in your joins.

Comment: Oh and the SET NOCOUNT is useless. You are counting! Besides, there is no other "interference" with your result set.

Comment: I wouldn't use `CHAR(20)` - that will pad all your strings to the defined length (20 characters) with spaces, and it will always use 20 bytes of storage - even if you only want to store `Hi` or something. Bad datatype choice! Use `Char(n)` if you have **short** codes, like 3-letter ISO country codes etc. - but don't use it for anything longer than maybe 5 characters or so!